# Getting "Access denied" with perl dbi when password is read from a file

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, dbi, variable-expansion

I am trying to write a simple perl script to pull the full contents of a table from a `MySQL` database using `DBI`.

I want to not have to put the database password in the script, so I'd like to set a password variable that reads from a file that contains the password.

I've got the script set up so that the three `DBI` parameters (`DSN`, `user` and `pass`) are variables. When I explicitly specify the password in the script, it works. When I have it read the file, it fails.

I even built in a small test to echo the `$pass` variable before calling `DBI` and that works great. It shows me the right password.

I'm certain that I'm doing something dumb. Help?

The environment:

---

~/mysql$ uname -a

```
Linux kbwm-radio-web 3.2.0-24-virtual #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 12:51:49 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

~/mysql$ perl --version

```
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
(with 41 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

~/mysql$ mysql -u phpuser -p`cat ./phpuser.auth` barret_test -e "status;"

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3
```

---

As you can see, using command expansion in the mysql statement for the password is functional.

The script (yes, parts of it are inelegant. That'll be fixed later):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:barret_test:localhost:3306";
my $user = "phpuser";
my $pass = qx{cat /home/barret/mysql/phpuser.auth};

print "$pass\n";


my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    $dsn,
    $user,
    $pass,
    { RaiseError => 1 },
) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $all = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("select name from users;");

foreach my $row (@$all) {
        my ($name) = @$row;
        print "$name\n";
}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Running it returns:

~/mysql$ perl user_list.pl

```
*redacted_password*


DBI connect('barret_test:localhost:3306','phpuser',...) failed: Access denied for user 'phpuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at user_list.pl line 14.
```

If I change line 9 from

```
my $pass = qx{cat /home/barret/mysql/phpuser.auth};
```

to

```
my $pass = "redacted_password";
```

This happens:

~/mysql$ perl user_list.pl

```
*redacted_password*

barret

richard

dave
```

I've Googled around and searched here, didn't see anything that seemed to cover my use case. I tried wrapping the `$pass` inside the `DBI` call in single and double quotes, no changes.

Comment: There's probably a newline after the password. `chomp` the variable to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it that way. MySQL provides a way to manage connection credentials using what they call [option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html). For example:

```
[client]
host = localhost
database = mydb
user = foo
password = bar
```

Make sure your file is not world-readable (0600 permissions on *nix). You can test that it's working using the command line client:

```
mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/file
```

To use an option file with DBI, do:

```
my $db_conf = '/path/to/file';
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:;mysql_read_default_file=$db_conf";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, undef, undef, { RaiseError => 1 }) or
        die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to do with the password being in a separate file.

Had to tweak it a little (in my version of mysql, it's "user" and not "username") but this is *EXACTLY* the end result I wanted.

Comment: Oops, good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a chomp to the script answered the question I asked.

```
my $pass = qx{cat /home/barret/mysql/phpuser.auth};
chomp ($pass);
```

Worked like a charm.

However... the solution I actually wanted was to use the mysql options_file.

```
my $db_conf = '/home/barret/mysql/phpuser.mysql';
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:;mysql_read_default_file=$db_conf";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, undef, undef, { RaiseError => 1 }) or
    die $DBI::errstr;
```

And inside the options file:

```
~/mysql$ cat phpuser.mysql
[client]
host = localhost
database = barret_test
user = phpuser
password = *redacted_password*
```

Resulting in:

```
$ perl user_list.pl
barret
richard
dave
```